# Android, Twitter4j, REST 1.1 - How do I finish the OAuth Process?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I have been at this since the weekend and I am at an impasse. I am pretty new to programming and suspect I am in over my head because I have read every link under "Similar Questions" and it either does not apply or confuses me more.

I am using the Twitter4j API and I worked from code sample no. 7 on the twitter4j website on OAuth support at http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html.

As a skill-building project, I want to make an Android celebrity fan app that will download the timeline from the celebrity's public account. The goal is to execute a timeline download of all the tweets. I do not want the user to login to Twitter with this app or post tweets. The app just downloads a timeline in the background and displays the tweets, probably in a list view.

My code is not executing the following line. It seems to just hang there waiting for something to happen. 
RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();

I have internet permissions in manifest. At this point, I am so confused, I do not even know if I have registered my app correctly. I have the four keys (consumer, consumer secret, access, and access secret).

**Settings**

-Website: made something up

-Application Type: Read Only

-Callback URL: left it blank

-I did not opt in to "Sign In With Twitter."

**OAuth Tool**

-Request Type: GET

-Request URI: https://api.twitter.com/1/ (probably wrong)

**This is my code:**

```
public class TwitterActivity extends Activity
{
    Button mButtonTweets;
    String JSONString = null;
    TextView JSONContent;

class GetTwitterTimeline extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {   
        try
        {
            ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
            .setOAuthConsumerKey("")
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret("")
            .setOAuthAccessToken("")
            .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("");
            TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
            Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

            try
            {
                RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();

                AccessToken accessToken = null;

                while (accessToken == null)
                {
                    onProgressUpdate(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL());

                    try
                    {
                        accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken();
                    }//try
                    catch(TwitterException te)
                    {
                        if (te.getStatusCode() == 401)
                        {
                            onProgressUpdate("Unable to get the access token");
                        }//if
                        else
                        {
                            te.printStackTrace();
                        }//else
                    }//catch
                }//while
                onProgressUpdate("Got Access Token");
                onProgressUpdate("Access Token: " + accessToken.getToken());
                onProgressUpdate("Access Token Secret: " + accessToken.getTokenSecret());
            }//try
            catch (IllegalStateException ie)
            {
                if(!twitter.getAuthorization().isEnabled())
                {
                    onProgressUpdate("OAuth consumer key/secret is not set.");
                }//if
            }//catch
        }//try
        catch (TwitterException te)
        {
            te.printStackTrace();
            onProgressUpdate("Failed to get timeline");
        }//catch

        String JSONString = "JSON content will go here";

        return JSONString;
    }//doInBackground

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String logEntry)
    {
        Log.d("twitter4j", logEntry);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String jsonString)
    {
        JSONString = jsonString;
    }

}//end inner class

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_twitter);

    new GetTwitterTimeline().execute();

    JSONContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_tweets);

    mButtonTweets = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_tweets);
    mButtonTweets.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            JSONContent.setText(JSONString);
        }
    });

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter API has been updated. So **Request URI: https://api.twitter.com/1/** won't work.

Also AFAIK the way you are trying to make the app won't work out. You need some kind of authentication. I also dumped one of my app after this API change. :(

Read the following link:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview

Comment: fida, I appreciate the comments. I have tried reading dev.twitter.com and it just confuses me more. I have also tried reading Stack Overflow, other sites that Google returns, and the twitter4j and Android APIs. I just get more confused. When you look at my code, do you see any obvious problems?

Comment: @JamesRogers: AFAIK your code is for login to twitter account and do various things. Not for pulling public posts. Reading public posts via JSON parsing was possible in older API. Not the latest API. Twitter has closed the door. :( 

You need to add login authentication for viewers in order to view posts and other works. Read the following link:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline